# Docker, redis, контейнер

Tags: docker, redis

Подскажите, как после запуска контейнера заставить выполниться в нем консольную команду без ручного захода в командную строку? Например, redis-cli config set requirepass 12345? Я что то запутался - многие пишут про какой то CMD но где его писать и как - что то не разобрался

Докер на винде крутится

спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Нужно создать в корне вашего проекта файл - Dockerfile. И уже там прописать, например:

```
CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

Для того, чтобы всё работало корректно, нужно прописать некоторые настройки, если вам это интересно, можете посмотреть это видео, там всё объясняют - [клик](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9uCgUzfeRQ) 
Тайминг видео вашей проблемы - 31:05

Comment: спасибо за ссылку, посмотрю, тут у меня звук не настроен, я так понимаю там голосом поясняют много. Не совсем понял, в корне проекта - это в www где сайт лежит?

Comment: @FrozenCoyote Да, он полностью объясняет работу Docker. Когда вы создаете свой проект, у него есть корневая папка, в которой всё лежит. Вот визуальный вам пример - [клик](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CHpc.png) Папка cds - это корневая папка проекта

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. К сожалению, на винде нет таких папок, которые Вы показали на скриншоте, видимо, тут все иначе.

Comment: @FrozenCoyote Везде есть такие папки, просто данная папка была открыта через редактор кода - vscode, так же можно использовать другие редакторы кода для этого. Скорее всего вы работает через панель управление сайтом, я так понял по вашему сообщению выше. Вы можете ( это уже зависит от того, где вы это делаете ) скачать и открыть корневую папку через редактор и загрузить все изменения обратно, но это уже другая тема разговора. Удачи)